# GeoDjango distance query ForeignKey

Tags: django, postgis, geodjango

I have a geCoded Address model and I have a user model has Address as foreignKey.
I can perform a distance calculation within the Address model easily by using the following

```
Address.objects.filter(geoCoords__distance_lt=(address1.geoCoords, D(mi=23)))
```

Address Model:

```
class Address(models.Model):

   streetAddress1 = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=300)
   city = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False,  max_length=50)
   state = USStateField(choices = US_STATES, blank=False, null=False,)
   zip5 = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=5, )
   zip4 = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=4, )
   geoCoords = models.PointField(null=False, blank=False, srid=4326)
   objects = models.GeoManager()
```

User Model:

```
class TestUsers
   ...
   location = models.ForeignKey(Address, null=True, blank=True)
   ...
```

I'd like to perform a query to get all TestUsers within certain distance of a pointField. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think your query should start with `TestUsers.objects.filter(..)`.

Comment: I have tried such construct, but since TestUsers itself does not use GeoManager, and only Address uses GeoManager, I am unable to use geoCoords__distance_lt.

Comment: Kindly add your `Location` model. I mean, `Address`.

Comment: Added the Address model to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
TestUsers.objects.filter(location__geoCoords__distance_lt=(address1, D(mi=23)))
```

Comment: Not working. Error "FieldError: Join on field 'geoCoords' not permitted. Did you misspell 'distance' for the lookup type?"

Comment: Try replacing `(address1.geoCoords, D(mi=23)))` with `(address1, D(mi=23)))` in which `address1` is your lookup points.

Comment: same error. It is not able to figure out __location_lt from location__geoCoords__distance_lt

Comment: Thanks. That looked promising. added models.GeoManager to TestUsers model. Now getting the following error "Cannot resolve keyword 'geoCoords_distance_lte' into field. Choices are:"

Comment: thanks for your help I posted the complete answer below.

Comment: Needed to add following to the model that is using Address as a ForeignKey

    objects = models.GeoManager() 

Once that is done, the following query resolves properly:

    TestUsers.objects.filter(location__geoCoords__distance_lte=(caddr.geoCoords, D(mi=21)))

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add following to the model that is using Address as a ForeignKey

```
objects = models.GeoManager()
```

Once that is done, the following query resolves properly:

```
TestUsers.objects.filter(location__geoCoords__distance_lte=(caddr.geoCoords, D(mi=21)))
```